# spark.executor.heartbeatInterval Spark Configuration

Tags: apache-spark

Adding below timeout values is giving me an exception :

Timeouts added:

```
spark.network.timeout=300000

spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=200000
```

Exception

```
spark.executor.heartbeatInterval should be less than or equal to spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs
```

I haven't set `blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs` anywhere in out application , we are using an EMR cluster, not sure from where blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs value is set.

Can someone help?